# URI Too Large, pass POST data without breaking this?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

So, I pass some values through AJAX to my PHP handler to generate a KML, but sometimes there's too much data and I get "Request-URI Too Large".  Is there another way I can pass the data with AJAX and JQuery to my PHP script?

Edit:  Disregard post, I was being stupid.  Issue is resolved.  Sorry about that guys.

Comment: and you say you ar eusing $_POST for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your AJAX calls, make sure you're setting it to [jquery.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) instead of [jquery.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get).  Check your (apache?) access log to see what URI is really being hit.  For POST, it should be a simple path to your script, and shouldn't contain all of your query terms like it would for a GET.

Answer (score 1):

Use POST, not GET in your request.

Answer (score 1):

use post!

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/q208427/